# How do I resolve this authentication error with OpenStack dashboard?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have successfully created a cloud using MAAS and juju from the documentation : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

Relation between dashboard and keystone successfully created. But I am unable to login from the web interface of dashboard. It gives an error:

```
Error: An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later.
```

I know while preparing these servers I used openstack.cfg file which has the password : openstack. But I am unable to login with that password.

Then I tried to ssh keystone machine and here is maybe something useful:

```
ls /var/lib/keystone/
cache  glance.passwd  keystone.db  keystone.token  s3_ec2_nova.passwd  s3_nova-volume_ec2_nova.passwd
```

I think this directory Should have a file called : `keystone.passwd` ?

I thought I can have a look to that file and get the random password by keystone, but that file does not exist.

`juju -v status`  shows that relation exists between dashboard and keystone.

So what do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Check your SELINUX status, put it in permissive mode. Your error shouldnt appear. You need to investigate the cause by checking /var/log/audit/audit.log

@ I just reproduced this error by setting SELINUX mode as enforcing.

you can check `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure` and the logs under `/var/log/http` for any openstack-related errors.